# _layout.cshtml not seeing object when at /Home/Index

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app.

I have an object of type `UserInfo` that is set (not important where).
Under `Shared`, my `_Layout.cshtml` shows the "Login ID" at the top in a menu bar.

The portion that shows this user name is in a `_LogInOutPartial.cshtml`
in the the partial view, I inspect the `UserInfo` object and set a variable `displayUser` accordingly: if the user object is null, I set the variable to "Guest", otherwise I pull the login id into this variable.

Code in _LogInOutPartial.cshtml is:

```
@model SisExtMvcAppSSO.Models.UserInfo;

@{
    bool isGuest = (Model == null || !Model.IsLogged);
    bool isLoggedIn = !isGuest;

    string displayUser = (isGuest ? "Guest" : Model.LoginId);
}
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">
    <i class="bi bi-person-badge"></i> @displayUser
</button>
```

When the object is set, if I go to some controller/action, e.g. `https://some.com/myApp/Home/Claims`, the login id shows fine (e.g. "mcollins") in the top menu bar.

However, if I go to `https://some.com/myApp/` (or `https://some.com/myApp/Home/Index` or `https://some.com/myApp/Home`), the menu bar (`_layout.cshtml`) will not show the login id, instead it shows "Guest"

This is even when the `/Home/Index` will show the login id in its view!
The problem is, apparently, the object it is not seen in `_Layout.cshtml`.

But then how come it is seen in the menu bar (`_Layout.cshtml`) when I go to `/Home/Claims`?

Comment: For a test, I set the object in the Home controller Index action, and return View(user) , and when I do this, the login id is shown in the top menu bar.

Comment: yeah, so I see that the _Layout.cshtml (and partial _LogInOut.cshtml) is expecting this object so if it is not passed in from the action, it will not render it in the top bar..

Comment: However, that means every single action in every controller has to pass obtain and pass this object, so that the _layout.cshtml can pick it up?? That seems unreasonable. Is there any way that this is done once from a central place?

Answer (score 0):

Usually,we will use `UserManager` as  the model in `_LogInOutPartial.cshtml` for Identity.If you don't want to use it,you can try to use Session and add the object to session in somewhere.Once the data is added,you can get it in other views.

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});


...
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
...
```

partial view:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;


@{
    UserInfo userInfo=null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Session.GetString("userInfo")))
    {
        userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(Context.Session.GetString("userInfo"));
    }
    
    bool isGuest = (userInfo == null || !userInfo.IsLogged);
    bool isLoggedIn = !isGuest;

    string displayUser = (isGuest ? "Guest" : userInfo.LoginId);
}
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">
    <i class="bi bi-person-badge"></i> @displayUser
</button>
```

Action:

```
 public IActionResult YourAction()
        {
            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo { LoginId = "mcollins", IsLogged = true };
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("userInfo", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInfo));
            return View();
        }
```